# Странная ошибка в GO

Tags: golang

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a int
    fmt.Scanln(&a)
    if a%2 == 0 && a < 0 {
        fmt.Println("Число отрицательное и четное")
    } else if a%2 == 1 && a < 0 {
        fmt.Println("Число отрицательное и нечетное")
    } else if a%2 == 0 && a >= 0 {
        fmt.Println("Число положительное и четное")
    } else if a%2 == 1 && a >= 0 {
        fmt.Println("Число положительное и нечетное")
    }
}
```

По какой-то причине последний if не работает, и на запрос -17 программа ничего не выводит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартная ошибка. `-1%2` возвращает -1. Изменённый код:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a int
    fmt.Scanln(&a)
    if a%2 == 0 && a < 0 {
        fmt.Println("Число отрицательное и четное")
    } else if a%2 == -1 && a < 0 {
        fmt.Println("Число отрицательное и нечетное")
    } else if a%2 == 0 && a >= 0 {
        fmt.Println("Число положительное и четное")
    } else if a%2 == 1 && a >= 0 {
        fmt.Println("Число положительное и нечетное")
    }
}
```

**Почему?**
Дело в том, что в большинстве языков `a%b` является **не** операцией **модуля**, а операцией **остатка от деления**. [Вот хорошая статья на эту тему](https://habr.com/ru/articles/421071/). Если же вам нужен **модуль**, то используйте следующую конструкцию: `((a%b)+b)%b`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Приму ответ через 5 минут

Comment: Почти уже написал тоже самое...

Answer (score 2):

Ответ **@ШвеевАлексей** полностью правильный, но ещё немного улучшу код:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a int
    fmt.Scanln(&a)
    if a < 0 {
        if a%2 == 0{
            fmt.Println("Число отрицательное и четное")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Число отрицательное и нечетное")
        }
    } else {
        if a%2 == 0 {
            fmt.Println("Число положительное и четное")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Число положительное и нечетное")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как раз хотел поправить этот момент, но только сейчас понял, что в golang нет inline if-ов... И решил уже не трогать этот момент)

Comment: Зачем нужны if после else?

Comment: @MBo понял, поправил.